# Changing text of closet div in an array of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2 border">
    <label for="month">Month 1 - 01/11/2019</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity[]" name="inputCity[]" value="550">
    <label for="Costs">Costs</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputcosts" name="costs" value="0">
    <label for="grossprofit"><b>Gross Profit</b></label><div id="grossp[]"></div>
 </div>
```

I am attempting to change the grossp[] text depending on what is input into the inputcosts box, using the following

```
$(document).on('change keydown paste input', '#inputcosts' , function() {
 var monthcalc = $(this).closest("input[name='inputCity[]']").val();    
 var gcost = monthcalc - this.value; 
 $(this).closest("div[id='grossp[]']").html(gcost);
});
```

The div is not updating and no error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: id is a uniques thing, you should use `class` attribute for `grossp`, like `class="grossp[]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), `.closest` checks self and all parents

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the **element itself** and traversing up through **its ancestors** in the DOM tree

---

It's because `#grossp[]` is not parent of `inputcosts`.

First select parent and then do `.find`

```
$(this).closest('.form-group').find("div[id='grossp[]']")
```

---

Since you select by ID, no need to find anything around, since ID is unique in page: `$('#grossp[]')`

---

By your naming `id='grossp[]'` it seems that there is multiple elements by same ID. **It's not possible/valid**. Only `name` attribute can contain `[]` to submit it as array of elements. Any other attribute is just plain text.